# Handle actor deletion undo in Unreal Editor?

Tags: editors, unreal

I have some objects pointing to a scene component of an actor:

```
class MyObject 
{
    USceneComponent* Component;
}
```

When the actor is deleted, all its components are also deleted. So when the delete action is undone (transaction undo), the component pointer (in `MyObject`) becomes invalid. This is not a problem, but the pointer must be updated after the redo (when the actor and its components are automatically re-created).

How can I detect which actor was created by the redo?

Comment: Are you not marking the property with `UPROPERTY()`?

Comment: No, I didn't use `UPROPERTY()` nor `UOBJECT` because I have tons of objects like that, and I don't know how `UPROPERTY ()` will affect performances. But I could use it. If I do, will it be reset automatically to point the new `USceneComponent`?

Comment: Possibly, I'm not sure, as this is also a problem I've never had come up with my custom objects. However not usin UPROPERTY means the garbage collector can prematurely collect those objects form under you, and could mean that reflection can't re-init pointers like that on undo.

Comment: Yes, if I had a mean to know when an actor is rebuilt by the redo mechanism, that would not be a problem.